# If $f(n) \in O(g(n))$ then prove that $O(f(n) + g(n)) = O(g(n))$

Tags: functions, asymptotics

I have to prove that if I have two functions $f$ and $g$ and $f \in O(g)$ then $$O(f(n) + g(n)) = O(g(n))$$ but I don't know how to do it. Any help will be appreciated :)
Thank you!

Comment: It would be good to include a little more of your understanding of the problem, for example the definition of the big O notation

Comment: Okay, the definition is as follows. if $$f \in O(g) \rightarrow  \exists c \gt 0 \exists n_0 \gt 0 \forall n \geq n_0 : f(n) \leq c* g(n)$$. And my understanding is that this notation gives you a set of function that grow maximal so fast as the expression in O. So we have to show that all the function in $O(g(n) + f(n))$ are also in $O(g(n))$ and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

as f(n) ∈ O(g) then ∃C1>0 ∃n0>0 ∀n≥n0:f(n)≤C1∗g(n)

note also that g(n) ≤ C2∗g(n) thus:
f(n) + g(n) ≤ C1∗g(n) + C2∗g(n) → f(n) + g(n) ≤ 2*max{C1,C2} *g(n)

and the claim follows.

Comment: Thank you! I noticed only one minor thing, technically $c1$ and $c2$ could be any positive number in $\Bbb R$, but you treat them as numbers in $\Bbb N$, right?

Comment: 1. technically c1 and c2 could be any positive number in R - yes.
2. you treat them as numbers in N, right? - no.

note that my comment is not a full and formal proof, just showing the essence and logic of such a proof. from here you can construct one with no problem =).